# how to verify that N points are on the same plane (but may not be perfectly)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given a collection of points in 3d. The value of each dimension can be visualized
[image]

When we visualize these points in 3d. They clearly are actually only live on a plane (but not perfectly), visualized bellow
[image]

My question is, what is a general approach to verify that any number of collection of points live on the same plane. Or more generally, any collection of points of dimenion m, actually live on n dimension space where n < m.

One way of doing such a job is to find 3 points to make a plane and iteratively test every point. However, this is not what I am looking for due to the fact that it is not generalizable for more than 3->2 dimension and if there is a slight amount of noise, the method falls apart. One approach I have tried is to find the SVD decomposition and decide by the eigenvalues. I am certain this problem has been solved principally but I am not sure how, I appreciate any opinion.

Comment: Pick 3 points, find the plane between them, then check whether the rest satisfy the plane equation.

Comment: If you can make a matrix 3 by 3 with the coords of 3 of these points,  with rank 3, then they lay not in the same plane.

Comment: Hi @DonThousand and dmtri , I have just edited and add additional info. Thanks for your opinion and I'd appreciate any additional insight.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking to do [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_Component_Analysis) instead? Applied to your example data, it would yield an orthonormal transform (rotation) around the coordinate mean, with the figure being on the $xy$ plane (with all $z$ coordinates being almost the same).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Total Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) technique is what you need.
If the points are *almost* layered into one plane (in any dimension), that method will reveal it
and will give you the measure of the *noise*.

But if the points layer into multiple planes, then you would need more sophisticated methods
ranging through SVD , [low-rank approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) or other methods.

In general, the problem falls into the category of [Point Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_cloud) analysis.

Comment: So SVD was one of the right track. Thanks :D

Comment: @Scicare Yes, indeed there is a strict connection between SVD and Least Squares.